# crm_mon command in new pacemaker not work as old behavior

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, pacemaker

I have installed pacemaker and corosync in my Redhat 7 machine.

I not see some resources(stopped resources) when node go to down(or service down). Below is my example:

When i using old pacemaker rpms. It work normally.

```
Online: [ node1 ]
OFFLINE: [ node2 ]

 Clone Set: test [ping]
    Started: [ node1 ]
    Stopped: [ node2 ]
```

Pacemaker version: pacemaker-1.1.10-29.el7.x86_64.rpm

When i using new pacemaker rpms:

```
Online: [ node1 ]
OFFLINE: [ node2 ]

 Clone Set: test [ping]
     Started: [ node2 ]
```

Pacemaker version: pacemaker-1.1.13-10.el7.x86_64.rpm

I want to use new pacemaker rpms and see all resource show as old behavior. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `crm_mon -r` to see full inactive resources.